# Is there a way to inspect full post request header and body before sending?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm sending a POST request, with python-requests in Python 3.5, using:

```
r = requests.post(apiEndpoint, data=jsonPayload, headers=headersToMergeIn)
```

I can inspect the headers and body *after* sending the request like this:

```
print(r.request.headers)
print(r.request.body)
```

Is there any way to inspect the *full* request headers (not just the ones i'm merging in) and body *before* sending the request?

Note: I need this for an api which requires me to build a hash off of a subset of the headers, and another hash off the full body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [Prepared Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests)